# Get the next element (not necessarily a sibling) which matches a selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this markup

```
<a class="foo"></a>
<div>
  <span class="foo"></span>
  <ul>
    <li class="foo"></li>
  </ul>
  <em class="foo"></em>
</div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

I'll have a click handler attached to `.foo`. I want to fetch the next element in the DOM tree that has the same class.

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/tXxng/) with the markup and js code, if you want to try out something.

I could make an array of all .foo elements, and then run loops to find the current index, and return the next index, but I'm sure there's a better solution. Also, that solution won't work if I add elements dynamically to the page (which I will).

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: Define what you mean by "next item" when someone clicks on an element with class=foo? Closest? Child? Sibling?

Comment: @j08691 This is the order I want: a.foo, span.foo, li.foo, em.foo, div.foo. Does that make it clear?

Comment: OK so if I click on em.foo, what do you want?

Comment: I want div.foo returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the next .foo element:

```
var foos = $('.foo');
$(".foo").click(function() {
    if($(foos).index(this) + 1 != foos.length)console.log(foos[$(foos).index(this) + 1]);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tXxng/1/)**

Updated code example for Dogbert's exact needs:

```
$(".foo").click(function() {
    var text = "Clicked on a: ";
    text += $(this)[0].tagName;
    text += "; Next is a: ";
    var foos = $(".foo");
    var probably = foos[foos.index(this) + 1];
    if(probably)
        text += probably.tagName;
    else
        text += "Nothing!";
    text += "<br/>";
    $("body").append(text);
});
```

​

Comment: `.index` looks like a good idea. This won't work if I add more `.foo`s dynamically, but I think its easy to modify. I'll try it out.

Comment: Should be trivial to modify for dynamically added elements. Just rebuild foos prior to the calculation.

Comment: Yes, it was. This is the complete answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/tXxng/6/. If you could add it to your answer, that would be great for anyone searching the question later. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @amnotiam I think just `this.tagName` would work there. Anyways, I'm not using that code in my site, it was just for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

j08691 was quicker, anyways this is what I came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/tXxng/9/

Basically, it's about the same of what `.index()` does; you iterate all the items and return the first one after the one matching, or the first item of the array if the matching was the last one (this circular behavior can be disabled, if that's not what you need).